# External package import error

Tags: c++

I am trying to import a package called libusb into a C++ source file  I am writing. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <libusb.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "hey there!" << endl;
}
```

When I run g++ and try to compile the code, I get this error:

```
launcherDriver.cpp:2:20: error: libusb.h: No such file or directory
```

But I know that libusb has been installed, because when I type yum install libusb, I get this:

```
Setting up Install Process
Package libusb-0.1.12-23.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

What do I need to do to successfully import the libusb package.

Comment: That looks like a message from `yum`, not `g++`. Are you compiling from a `Makefile` or something similar?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. Now read my question.

Comment: Usually the terminology is `include library headers`, or `link library` rather than `import package`.

Answer (score 2):

Use you yum-utils to see package contents

> repoquery -lq libusb

Probably you libusb.h is inside a directory not seen by compiler. Using this command you will easily identify it. After that, change your program to include it correctly

```
#include <directory/libusb.h>
```

Probably, directory will be libusb-1.0 or something like that. Or you can tell the compiler to include this directory too, in order to generate this objects. Do that with -I directive:

> g++ -I/usr/include/libusb-1.0 -c launcherDriver.cpp

Comment: My /usr/include folder has no libusb folder. /usr/lib64 has a libusb-1.0.so.0 file and libusb-1.0.so.0.0.0

Comment: So, try to install libusb-devel